# Implementation of Newton's method of finding root of a function

Tags: c#, numerical-methods

The following is an implementation of Newton's method of finding root of a function.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using ZedGraph;

//Newton's Method  
//https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GrfaB88w4M&t=350s
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915317/how-to-find-derivative-of-a-function-using-c
//https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-for-newton-raphson-method/
namespace _1_22_Newton_Method_of_Root_Finding
{
    public delegate double MyFunction(double x);
    public class RootFinder
    {
        static double EPSILON = 0.01;
        static double h = 1.0e-6;

        public static double Derivative(MyFunction func, double x0)
        {
            double x1 = x0 - h;
            double x2 = x0 + h;
            double y1 = func(x1);
            double y2 = func(x2);
            double der = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);//<==== i am not sure about this.

            return der;
        }

        private static double NextNewton(MyFunction func, double guess)
        {
            return guess - func(guess) / Derivative(func, guess); 
        }

        public static double Newton(MyFunction func, double init)
        {
            double x = init;
            double y = NextNewton(func, x);

            //for(int i=0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
            while(Math.Abs(y) >= EPSILON)
            //while(true)
            {
                y = NextNewton(func, x);

                if (x == y)
                {
                    break;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Root = {0}", y);
                x = y;
            }

            return y;
        }
    }
```

Kindly, review the source code.

Does this source code have any pitfall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Math.Abs(y) >= EPSILON`

I think this condition is only satisfied for roots around zero on the x-axis. Maybe you confuse yourself by naming the next `x` as `y`? A better name would be `x1`.

The actual continue condition should be `Math.Abs(x - x1) >= EPSILON` and you then can skip the test `if (x == y) break;`

---

Your rather large value of `EPSILON` may result in imprecise roots now and then.

---

You can clean up the main algorithm to something like:

```
public static double Newton(MyFunction func, double init)
{
  double x;
  double x1 = init;

  do
  {
    x = x1;
    x1 = NextNewton(func, x);

    Console.WriteLine("Root = {0}", x1);
  } while (Math.Abs(x - x1) >= EPSILON);

  return x1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double der = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);//<==== i am not sure about this.
```

You got it right.

---

The function `Derivative` can return 0, in which case you'll end up dividing by 0 at the function `NextNewton`.